# utc to pst conversion in impala

Tags: hive, impala, pst

In Impala for some of the timestamp I am getting incorrect data while converting from UTC to PST.When i run same query in hive i am getting correct data but in impala PST conversion is not doing properly for some of the dates.

Impala:

```
select from_utc_timestamp('2006-08-30 08:00:00','PST')
2006-08-30 01:00:00
```

Hive:

```
select from_utc_timestamp('2006-08-30 08:00:00','PST')
2006-08-30 00:00:00
```

To overcome is there anyother way to convert utc to PST

Answer (score 0):

Use below timezone conversions in Impala.
    from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)

```
timezone :
for Eastern Time:  America/New_York or EST5EDT
for Central Time:  America/Chicago or CST6CDT
for Mountain Time: America/Denver or MST7MDT
    Phoenix  won't observe daylight saving time: America/Phoenix

for Pacific Time:  America/Los_Angeles or PST8PDT
for Alaska Time:   America/Anchorage or America/Juneau
for Hawaii Time:   America/Adak or EST5EDT
    Honolulu  won't observe day light saving time: Pacific/Honolulu

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-03-11 13:41:22.084','America/Los_Angeles')
    2017-03-11 05:41:22.084000000                                        

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-03-12 13:41:22.084','America/Los_Angeles')
    2017-03-12 06:41:22.084000000                                       

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-03 13:41:22.084','America/Los_Angeles')
    2017-11-03 06:41:22.084000000                                    

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-04 13:41:22.084','America/Los_Angeles')
   2017-11-04 06:41:22.084000000                                        

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-05 13:41:22.084','America/Los_Angeles')
   2017-11-05 05:41:22.084000000
```

---

```
**Daylight saving time(2017) ends at 2:00 AM on Sunday, November 5**   
select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-05 08:58:00.000','America/Los_Angeles')
  2017-11-05 01:58:00 (UTC -7hrs)                                                

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-05 08:59:00.000','America/Los_Angeles')
  2017-11-05 01:59:00 (UTC -7hrs)                                                   

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-05 09:00:00.000','America/Los_Angeles')
  2017-11-05 01:00:00   (UTC -8hrs)                                               

select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-05 09:01:00.000','America/Los_Angeles')
  2017-11-05 01:01:00  (UTC -8hrs)
```

Comment: This does not look like a S.O. *answer* -- it's just a list of observations (not easy to read BTW), without any explicit conclusion or recommendation. Can you edit your answer to *(a)* format the code samples with `Code Sample` style; *(b)*  elaborate on the root cause e.g. _"PST is ambiguous and interpreted differently in Java (Hive) and C++ (Impala)"_ (I'm just guessing there); *(c)* propose a workaround?

Comment: select from_utc_timestamp('2017-11-05 13:41:22.084','America/Los_Angeles')
This is not working.

Comment: I added DST changes for Nov 5 2017.I executed this on CDH5.7.6 and not seeing any issue.